# Jenkins - docker: command not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh

Pretty simple, I added SSH, with credentials and etc., no problem,
Then 
I created Job with *Executing shell script on remote host using ssh*

```
!/bin/sh
docker --version
```

got the error:

```
[SSH] script:

#!/bin/sh
docker --version

[SSH] executing...
bash: line 2: docker: command not found

[SSH] completed
[SSH] exit-status: 127
```

I can do `ls -l`...
I can run any shell files on remote linux box, except **docker**,
 
I am really stuck.
Anybody knows what should I do?

Comment: Have you installed docker on the machine?  It likely doesn't come pre-installed.  What O/S are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ran Jenkins on Windows box, but docker installed on remote Debian box.Should I have docker installed on Windows box also? I ran docker installation last night on Windows box and will try one more time today.